# Applescript Question - Like Track (Spotify)

Tags: macos, applescript, spotify

I use [MTMR](https://github.com/Toxblh/MTMR) (My TouchBar My rules). I want create a script to set a like to track at Spotify.

```
tell application "Spotify"
  ...?
end tell
```

How can I set like to current track?